# Enable .htaccess in localhost server

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to change the url of my webpage at localhost but i am unable to figure it out. I am using windows 7(64 bits).
I already uncomment the "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so" and AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All.

I want to change my url "http://localhost/mywebsite/product_name.php?name=alfa" to something like that "http://localhost/product_name/alfa"

My .htaccess file code is below:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ product_name.php?name=$1 [L]"
```

my php file code is:

```
<a href="product_name.php?name='$name'">..... </a>
```

Please help me I tried many changes in my htaccess file but could not find a solution

Comment: are you using xampp? please share your httpd-vhost configuration for url

Answer (score 0):

Change your php code to:

```
<a href="'$name'">..... </a>
```

Or add this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+product_name\.php\?name=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
```

Comment: and if i changed my php code then how i get the value of name on another page.... please answer